# What is an "07" chord?

Tags: notation

What chord does "D#07" refer to? I'd guess it's a kind of D# or D#7?

```
/Em              C       /D                          /Em  /    /
 Baby, I've been waiting, I've been waiting night and day.
Em               Cmaj7/D               /Em           /
I didn't see the time, I waited half my life away.
          /D                  /D                     /D#07 /B+7
There were lots of invitations and I know you sent me some,
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks as if it could be a [diminished seventh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminished_seventh_chord). On D#, the notes would be D#, F#, A and C. The customary notation is a superscript circle, but perhaps whoever printed the sheet music you saw couldn't produce that character and so typed a zero instead.

Comment: Can I ask: Would the following B+7 be a B augmented 7th chord?

Comment: @Anna - more than likely! The B+7 keeps D# and A from the D#o chord, changing only the F# and C to Fx and B respectively, then to Em. B7  (and B+7) changes to E/Em 9 times out of 8...

Comment: Thank you Tim! Maybe I should make a habit out of spelling out the notes to see how they move through chord changes. I've just learnt by heart how the notes move from V7 to I, no other chords.

Comment: Possibly a result of multiple copying of the stuff. First person didn't have a superscript `°` on his keyboard and wrote `o` which is ugly but customary; second person replaced `o` with `0` carelessly.

Comment: Or maybe the chord is actually meant to be half-diminished (`ø`), and they tried to express that by `0` which is sometimes rendered with a slash through it??

Comment: Thank you @anatolyg, that would have made sense too! I've found proper sheet music for this song (Waiting for the Miracle by Cohen and Sharon Robinson), and there it's written as D#dim7.

Answer (score 5):

It's a *diminished seventh* chord. A diminished chord consists of root, m3, d5, as in C E♭ G♭, or in the case above it would be D♯o - D♯ F♯ A.

Adding a seventh to this produces the *diminished seventh* chord. Using D♯ as the root, it will be C.

Answer (score 5):

D#07 means D#o7 whereby the o should be written like a degree sign: uppercase!
If I copy it from this [link](https://www.ascii-code.com/) it is written normally, I know how to type it in word, but in SE it doesn't work:

D#o7 = D#°7 = dim7, stands for diminished seventh chord: root, min 3rd, dim 5th, dim 7th

The notes of D# dim7 are D#,F#,A,C

As you can see it is related to the B 9 chord - without root tone.

Edit:

every (vii o7)  can be considered as a (V b9) without root and like the B+7 is probably a secondary dom. 7b9 chord to e-minor the 5th of this chord can be augmented for both progressions: D# dim7 and B7 => B +7 (the + is related to the fifth and means B 7 (#5)

Comment: Please check first three 'words'! And B9 usually has C# rather than C.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the relation to B9, interesting! Is there some insight to be gained from that in this particular case, e.g. the relating to the following Baug7?

Comment: I meant to give this hint too:  every (vii o7)   can be considered as a V7) without root and like the B+7 is probably a secondary dom.7 chord to e-minor the 5th of this chord can be augmented for both progressions: D# dim7 and B7 => B +7 (the + is related to the fifth and means B 7 (#5)

Comment: Regarding "every (vii o7) can be considered as a V7) without root", don't you mean "V(b)9 without root"?

Comment: Yes, I’ve forgotten the b9.

Comment: FYI, to get that or other symbols in SE, you can use Character Map (Windows) or Key Caps (Mac) and pick them from the chart: ° (degree symbol) or º (superscript zero).

Comment: ° on my windows keyboard, yes,  and also charmap  (app) thanks  a lot, I didn't know this app. I've been wasting so much time searching those symbols on the Ipad. ;)